# How to bring back only nested documents fitting filter

Tags: mongodb, embedded-documents

I have created a mongodb collection where the schema is as follows.

```
{user_id, listings: <Array of Documents>, ...}
```

In the listing documents I have a field named **status** which has two values *publish* and *draft*.

In mongo shell I am trying to bring back only the user listings with **status**:*publish*
So I run the bellow command and I keep getting back also documents with **status**:*draft* that are part of the user with published listings.

```
db.properties.find({'listings.status':'publish'},{'listings.status':1, _id:0})
```

Outputs:

```
[
  { listings: [ { status: 'draft' } ] },
  { listings: [ { status: 'publish' } ] },
  { listings: [ { status: 'draft' }, { status: 'publish' }, { status: 'draft' } ] },
  { listings: [ { status: 'publish' }, { status: 'draft' } ] },
  { listings: [ { status: 'publish' } ] }
]
```

How can I get an array back of the listings with only status: publish ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an aggregation pipeline with a `$filter`:

1. `$filter` the `listings` field to contain only items with status `publish`.
2. `$match` only documents with `$size` of `listings` greater than 0.
3. format

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      listings: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$listings",
          as: "item",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$item.status",
              "publish"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$match: {$expr: {$gt: [{$size: "$listings"}, 0]}}},
  {$project: {listings: 1, _id: 0}}
])
```

[Playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e0FzRBFUhTy)

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. In the PlayGround example I still see draft and publish as the final result or am I missing something? New to mongo querying and I appreciate the help

Comment: Do you want to remove the { status: 'draft' } from the array OR do you want to get back only documents that contain { status: 'publish' } in the array? OR both?

Comment: What is the expected output from the playground data?

Comment: I want to get back only  documents with status publish

Comment: The expected outputs is the listings data where listing has publish status

Comment: Like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MEDht4aixcH) ?

Comment: Now I am getting back results as  ```{ listings: [] }, { listings: [] }```  , there are more fields in the embedded document other than status. Probably have not structured my question well. The result in the playground seems correct. I will look into it a bit more

Comment: If you will provide the requested output from the playground data, I will be able to help you

Comment: Correction I am getting back the published listings but also the empty arrays of users that do not have any published. Is there a way to omit them ?

Comment: Sure: https://mongoplayground.net/p/e0FzRBFUhTy